# print raw http headers in ruby

Tags: ruby

for example, in shell, I could use curl & do

```
curl -I http://google.com
```

and it would print out raw http headers. what's the alternative of this in ruby?

Question being, how to print `raw http headers` in Ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require 'open-uri'
open("http://google.com"){|f| p f.meta }
```

Comment: It does not return raw headers but outputs them as hash. thanks!

Btw, is p alias to print/puts?

Comment: `p` here is `puts f.meta.inspect`, intended to have programmer-friendly output.